# Echo php using CSS Content: property

Tags: php, html, css

I need to echo php using css Content: property.

PHP:

```
<?php
$links = "<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"images/fb.png\"     width=\"16\" height=\"16\"></a> <a href=\"https://twitter.com\" target=\"_blank\"><img     src=\"images/twitter.png\" width=\"16\" height=\"16\"></a>";
?>
```

CSS:

```
body li:nth-child(2):after{ 
content: "<?php echo "$links"; ?>";
color:#FFF;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>date</li>
<li>time</li>
</ul>
```

Desired Output:

```
Date  Time  FB  TW
```

Comment: Are you trying to use PHP code in CSS file? IT's not working in that way. Use templating engine (Smarty, LESS, SASS) if you want to use variables in your CSS. Or embed CSS in PHP, if you don't mind mixing CSS and PHP code (that's not good).

Comment: it seems like you are mixing a few things...PHP will not use CSS, but you can echo CSS statements via PHP as part of your text output. On the other had, usually .css files will not be interpreted by the php engine, so it is a bit confusing what you are trying to do here. And another thing: the string in your `$link` variable doesn't look like a valid entry in a CSS `content:` property

Comment: I could write the whole in PHP and output the CSS to include the images after each second list item, but I am using a CMS on the site and the Date and Time is coming from this CMS which doesn't use PHP (very confusing). This seemed like the best method for me to manage where the images appear through the CSS file. If using PHP within CSS content: is not possible then I will have try another method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
CSS:
body li:nth-child(2):after{ 
    content: "<?php echo $links; ?>";
    color:#FFF;
}
```

You can also try like

```
content: <?php echo $links; ?>;
```

Assuming that your `CSS` is in the same file as with `PHP`

Comment: @Aviator is it so?No it will work.He is dealing with the `PHP` also, not only html.

Comment: We assumed CSS is on the same PHP page, not on an external static CSS file (obviously)

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Sorry for missunderstanding the question. I should not read/write and drive... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
content: "<?php echo $links; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes when echoing to CSS. Modify as follows:

```
content: "<?php echo $links; ?>";
```

Comment: Hi, This just outputs the following:
Date Time <?php echo $links; ?>

Comment: In what file is the CSS code? If the CSS is on an external (and static) .css file, the PHP will, obviously, not be executed and the php tags are printed as plain text.
You have to place the CSS in the same PHP page.

Comment: Thank you Carmine, That makes sense and works with plain text, but I think the variable content of anchors and images is the issue now, as it does not seem to be outputting.

Comment: It's obvious, you can't put PHP code in a static file.